# Procedure to delete a customer

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following procedure, which is supposed to delete a specific customer. I keep getting errors, and I am not sure why.  I am new to this and this is a class homework.

Thanks in advance for your help:

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE DISP_CUST_DELETE (I_CUSTOMER_NUM IN CUSTOMER_NUM&TYPE)

BEGIN 
    DELETE
    FROM  CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUSTOMER_NUM = I_CUSTOMER_NUM;

    dbms_output.put_line('Customer has been deleted');

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('NO CUSTOMER WITH this number has been deleted');
END;
/
```

Here is a little update.
Yes, sorry that is what I meant.  Here is the updated procedure.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE DISP_CUST_DELETE (I_CUSTOMER_NUM IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM) AS

BEGIN 
    DELETE
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUSTOMER_NUM = I_CUSTOMER_NUM;

    dbms_output.put_line('Customer' || I_CUSTOMER_NUM ||'has been deleted');

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('NO CUSTOMER WITH'||I_CUSTOMER_NUM||'has been deleted');
END;
/
```

And here is the error I am getting:

> 0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated 1/47
>   PLS-00488: 'CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM' must be a type

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: By `CUSTOMER_NUM&TYPE` you probably meant `CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM%TYPE`?

Comment: Please update the QUESTION, not in another comment. The comment is not formatted.

Comment: Now you just have `CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM` not `CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM%TYPE`. Add the `%TYPE` at its end...

Comment: Thank you so much, I was using & instead of %.  Now it works.  You all are awesome, especially sticky bit.

Answer (score 0):

Like `@sticky bit` suggested in the comments, you have a syntax error on your code.
In order for you to declare a variable to be the same type as a previously declared variable or a column of a table you should use `table.table_column%TYPE`.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE DISP_CUST_DELETE (
    I_CUSTOMER_NUM IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM%TYPE   --> This line here
) AS

BEGIN 
    DELETE
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUSTOMER_NUM = I_CUSTOMER_NUM;

    dbms_output.put_line('Customer' || I_CUSTOMER_NUM ||'has been deleted');

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('NO CUSTOMER WITH'||I_CUSTOMER_NUM||'has been deleted');
END;
/
```